# Solr query fl paramter: help needed

Tags: solr

I am trying to return specific fields in my Solr query using the fl parameter.

However, I have a scenario where I want to fetch one of the 'inner' field from a specific field. The scenario is like this:

I have fields like: id, name, type, xml_blob. the xml_blob element is of type `<str>` and contains a set of xml tags, like: `<StartDate><EndDate><AvailableIndicator>` etc.

Is it possible to fetch the `<AvailableIndicator>` value using fl parameter? I do not want to specify the entire xml_blob element but want to get only this single value.

Please help.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. fl does not provide an xpath evaluator on the string.
You have to handle it at the Client side to index the content or retrieve the value from the response.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. Is there a possibility to handle it in the main query? Example: xml_blob: <some value> ?